# ASP.Net db connection issue

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to ASP.Net & SQL Server and have the following code:

```
protected void btnShowData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString;
            SqlConnection cnn;

            connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-RV7DDL4;Initial Catalog=Demodb
                ;User ID=DESKTOP-RV7DDL4\dbname;Password=test123";

            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataReader dataReader;
            String sql, Output = "";

            sql = "Select TutorialID, TutorialName from demotb";
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + "</br>";
            }

            Response.Write(Output);

            dataReader.Close();
            command.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();

            lblName.Visible = false;
            txtName.Visible = false;
            lstLocation.Visible = false;
            chkC.Visible = false;
            chkASP.Visible = false;
            rdMale.Visible = false;
            rdFemale.Visible = false;
            btnSubmit.Visible = false;
        }
```

When I run the project I receive the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

I thought the connection was made so not sure why it says the db is closed?

Comment: Please try to reduce the example code to just the minimum necessary to display the issue. All the stuff about "lblName.Visible" etc is noise. Also, the code could use some better formatting. You should also point to where the  exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to to explicitly open the connection via the [Open method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx) on the SQL connection class.

Perhaps a using statement is more appropriate here. Like so:

```
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Use the connection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I re-jigged things around and added the .Open method and it works!

```
string connectionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn;
            SqlCommand command;
            string sql, Output = "";

            connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-RV7DDL4\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DemoDBase
                ;User ID=sa;Password=test1234";

            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            sql = "Select TutorialID, TutorialName from demoTable";



            cnn.Open();

            command = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
            SqlDataReader dataReader;
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Output = Output + dataReader.GetValue(0) + " - " + dataReader.GetValue(1) + "</br>";
            }

            Response.Write(Output);

            dataReader.Close();
            command.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();
```